# Is there anyway to generate two vectors whose correlation are very different in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, vector

if I have vectorA = [1 1 -1]; and vectorB = [-1 -1 1], and vectorC = [1 1 -1]

Correlation means the similarity of two vectors.

So Correlation(vectorA,vectorB) = vectorA*vectorB = -3

Correlation(vectorA,vectorC) = 3;

That means vectorA and vectorC are similar because the correlation is high enough.

and correlation of vectorA and vectorB are more different because the correlation is low enough.

My trouble is How can I generate **SIX** vectors and their correlation is low enough?That means I want these two vectors so different in every element of vector.

Is there any wise way to generate or somehow? Thanks everyone.

PS: elements in vector are all +1 or -1.

Comment: That is an orthogonality question, if the vectors are orthogonal `Corr(a,b)=0`, if they point in same direction `Corr(a,b)>0`, if they point in opposite directions `Corr(a,b)<0`. I.e. you should take any vector `a` and rotate it 180 degrees to get the lowest "correlation" vector possible. And the same vector for the largest correlation.

Comment: First, how do you define correlation? Is it +1 for every element that matches and -1 for every that doesn't? Second, how do you mean generate a vector that is low in correlation? You can simply define `B=-A`. Every element will then be different, except for zero. This is probably not what you mean.

Comment: Take any vector `a`, then the lowest correlation vector will be `-a`.

Comment: I don't understand your question. When you want the vector to be different in each element, `-a` is the only possibility. There is no possibility to generate 6 different vectors where this condition is true.

Comment: thank u @zeroth
I got it

Answer (score 1):

If you define correlation as the [Dot Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) between 2 vectors then the definition is equivalent to [Orthogonality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality) of the Vectors.

In your case, your space is R ^ 3, which means you can not find more than 3 vectors which are Orthogonal to each other (Namely, has no correlation).

If you need 6 which has the lowest correlation, well it is all about their direction.
Since the direction is the issue, let's assume all of them are normalized of have a norm of 1.
Then think about the [Unit Circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle) and just divide it into 6 direction which the angle between them is equal, just like you'd slice a Pizza.